# Observer event after placing an order issue in Magento

Tags: magento-1, event-observer

This is my xml:

```
<global>
  <frontend>
            <events>
                <sales_quote_save_before>
                    <observers>
                        <mynamespace_mymodule_sales_quote_save_before>
                            <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observers_CheckoutValidation</class>
                            <method>orderValidation</method>
                        </mynamespace_mymodule_sales_quote_save_before>
                    </observers>
                </sales_quote_save_before>
            </events>
        </frontend>

    </global>
```

This is my observer:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Observers_CheckoutValidation
{
    public function orderValidation($o){
        Mage::log('My log entry', null, 'mylogfile.log');
    }
```

BY creating the log file I just want to know if it gets there. but the file is never created. What I want to achieve is to validate some fields (address,telephone etc) in an observer. Why my log file is not created?

Comment: use sales_order_place_after event

Comment: not working , but i want a before event, not after